# Struts Passing Static Class Name Through Include

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jspinclude

I'm attempting to reduce code by creating a include for a common block of code I have bewtween two JSPs. However, I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out how to pass this include parameters with struts.

In the parent JSP, I have this:

```
<s:include value="../path_to_include.jsp">
  <s:param name="someClass" value="com.package.ClassName" />
</s:include>
```

Within the include:

```
<s:set name="staticClassMember" value="%{@someClass@STATIC_CLASS_MEMBER}" />
```

Which causes struts to fail. So I have a few issues here:

1. How can I pass this class name and access it as a variable in the included JSP?
2. I tried setting struts.devMode to true in my struts.xml, but this doesn't seem to give me an error, this included JSP just doesn't show up. Without any error messages, I'm pretty much at a loss why this is failing/how to fix it. Is there another setting I need for struts in order to have this produce an error?
3. Where can I find some good documentation for this?

I'd like to not have to include each static variable as a separate argument to the include.

Comment: OGNL's `@...@...` notation is specifically to access static properties by immediate name; no interpolation of variables will be done. What on earth is your usecase? There's likely a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you try it with <s:action name="YOURACTION" executeResults="true"/> ? You can pass parameter from action class without any hassle